# Angular 2 - styles dont work in AOT build

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using this function to add style to my component if the parameter `widget=true` is present in the url:

```
addStyleSheet() {
  var headID = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.id = 'widget_styles';
  headID.appendChild(link);

  link.href = './app/open-account/open-account-widget-styles.component.css';
}
```

It works perfectly when built Just In Time (JIT) but does not work when built in Ahead Of Time (AOT).  Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to this, but I can tell you one thing that's certain: interacting directly with the DOM API is generally considered bad practice. If you need to dynamically apply styles to a component, consider using an attribute directive on the component's root tag.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a simple example to explain this.
Imagine this is your route:

```
{ path: '/widget', component: WidgetComponent }
```

You can navigate to that route with parameters using the following code:

```
this.router.navigate(
  ['/widget'], { queryParams: { widget: 'true' } }
);
```

This will result in the following URL `/widget;widget=true` Note: Angular uses an semicolons for separating the params instead of a question mark.

Documentation can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html)

In your component you can get the params like this:

```
this.route
  .queryParams
  .subscribe(params => {
    this.widget = params['widget'] === 'true';
  });
```

At this point you have a variable with the param in your component you can now use conditional styling.

```
<div [ngClass]="{class_name: widget}">Lorum ipsum</div>
```

This way you never touch the DOM directly and angular will handle everything.